# Logo light source placement on CRJ 900

Tags: bombardier-crj, aircraft-external-lights

I understand that for most commercial aircraft, the source of the logo lights originates from the horizontal stabilizer which is projected onto the vertical stabilizer. However, I don't see how this could work for the CRJ 900 or other aircraft with a T-tail configuration. Can these aircraft also have logo lights, and if so where would the light originate from?

Comment: Surely a light can shine _down_ from the horizontal stabilizer to the vertical stabilizer?

Answer (score 3):

The Bombardier CRJ series has the logo lights installed on the engine pylons:

> [image: CRJ lights]
>
> **E. Logo Lighting**
>
> A white logo light is installed on the upper surface of each engine pylon to illuminate the
> airline logo on each side of the vertical stabilizer. The lights are controlled by a LOGO
> switch on the EXTERNAL LTS panel.
>
> [image: CRJ lights panel]

<sup>([Bobmardier CRJ-700/-900 FCOM - Lighting](https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/CRJ-00_and_00-Lighting.pdf))</sup>

Some other aircraft with a T-tail have the logo lights installed on the lower surface of the horizontal stabilizer, e.g. the Dash-8 Q400:

> [image: Q400 Tail lights]
>
> **12.14.5.8 Logo Lights**
>
> White logo lights are installed flush with the bottom left and right horizontal stabilizers. The logo
> lights supply lighting for the logo on the vertical stabilizer.

<sup>([Bombardier Dash-8 Q400 FCOM - Lighting System](https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/Q400-Lighting_System_1.pdf))</sup>

Comment: on 737s (at least the older ones) the logo light is out on the wingtip.

Comment: @Anilv That's weird, never heard of that before. Newer ones have them on the horizontal stabilizer. But the 737 is not a T-tail of course.

Comment: [This link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/wbaiv/4085635596/) shows how some 737 classics had logo lights installed on the wingtips, although it was an option & plenty of classics didn't have them. All NG & Max 737s, AFAIK, have logo lights, which are on the horizontal stab.

Comment: And [this photo](https://l7.alamy.com/zooms/2c03f9d4c21342e0a441987d481e4493/wingtip-on-easyjet-boeing-737-300-at-dusk-above-the-clouds-romantic-annxeb.jpg) shows what the light on the wintip itself looked like on those Classics which had them.